# Can't invoke list() method on QueryDslJdbcTemplate

Tags: jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc, querydsl

I'm using Spring jdbc to get distinct element of a specific column:

```
template.newSqlQuery().from(qCustomer).groupBy(qCustomer.name).list(qCustomer.name);
```

According to the official [documentation of querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02s04.html) all seems right

But i'm getting this:

```
GRAVE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysema.query.sql.AbstractSQLQuery.iterateSingle(AbstractSQLQuery.java:434)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.AbstractSQLQuery.iterate(AbstractSQLQuery.java:367)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.AbstractSQLQuery.list(AbstractSQLQuery.java:488)
    at com.dao.springdata.SpringDataLogRecordDAO.selectRecord(SpringDataLogRecordDAO.java:167)
    at com.domain.logic.LogRecordServiceImpl.selectRecord(LogRecordServiceImpl.java:41)
    at com.restservice.IOSLogsReporter.datatables(IOSLogsReporter.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:167)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1347)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1279)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1219)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:886)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:834)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
19 avr. 2013 20:56:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet default a g?n?r? une exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysema.query.sql.AbstractSQLQuery.iterateSingle(AbstractSQLQuery.java:434)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.AbstractSQLQuery.iterate(AbstractSQLQuery.java:367)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.AbstractSQLQuery.list(AbstractSQLQuery.java:488)
    at com.dao.springdata.SpringDataLogRecordDAO.selectRecord(SpringDataLogRecordDAO.java:167)
    at com.domain.logic.LogRecordServiceImpl.selectRecord(LogRecordServiceImpl.java:41)
    at com.restservice.IOSLogsReporter.datatables(IOSLogsReporter.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:167)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1347)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1279)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1219)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:886)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:834)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Did i miss something ?
Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: I just updated the post

Comment: which Querydsl version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This alternative works fine:

```
template.query(template.newSqlQuery().from(qCustomer).groupBy(qCustomer.name), qCustomer.name);
```

Comment: Yes, it appears the SQLQuery instance returned from newSqlQuery() doesn't have the connection attached. This seems to be indeed the way it's supposed to be used with Spring Data JDBC

Comment: Any update on that issue? I am facing the same problem with the list method and Spring querydslJdbcTemplate.. If it is the way it's supposed to be used with Spring JDBC, how do we do for SubQueries ? In my case I want to make dynamic union all of a list of subqueries.. But for each subquery, I must specify the projection .list(Wildcard.all)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JDBC connection of the query is null https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/blob/QUERYDSL_2_2_2/querydsl-sql/src/main/java/com/mysema/query/sql/AbstractSQLQuery.java#L434

Comment: If i remove **list(qCustomer.name)** it works fine. Please note that i use also the same jdbc connection to get other data and it works well so i don't think that is a JDBC connection issue

Comment: If you are using a transaction bound connection, make sure the method is transactional.